# docker run --volume mapping ignored

Tags: docker

I successfully run PostgreSQL thus:

```
$ docker run --name postgresql --env POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --publish 6000:5432 --volume /home/russ/dev/pg:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
```

only to find that:

```
$ docker inspect postgresql
...
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "06d27a1fe489cedfa47d6a3e801cb286494958e1c3a17f044205629cc7070952",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/06d27a1fe489cedfa47d6a3e801cb286494958e1c3a17f044205629cc7070952/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
...
```

Docker's usual, random filesystem backing is used instead of the hard-coded path I tried to map. Why is this or what should I have done instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Postgres Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/alpine/images/sha256-7d6403121b12c9d29c13c9873bc0f76da8ff51f6c89fae10b99dc890807e27ae?context=explore), you'll see a `VOLUME [/var/lib/postgresql/data]`.

This command creates the default, "anonymous" volume you're seeing and takes precedence over the `--volume` argument you provide with the CLI (as well as any commands in "child" `Dockerfile`s or configuration in `docker-compose` files).

This extremely annoying quirk of Docker applies to other commands as well  is currently being debated in https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465. This [comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465#issuecomment-129599700) describes a similar problem with `mysql` images.

Unfortunately, there isn't an easy workaround but here are some common methods I've seen used:

- Reconfigure Postgres to work out of a different directory and mount to that instead
- Have another container mount to the same anonymous volume and to your machine and have it copy data over periodically

If you just want the data persist between container starts, I would recommend keeping it in the anonymous volume to keep it simple.